# how can i refresh / update adding class to td:contains when text changes

Tags: jquery

I am using this to add a class to a td that contains certain text

```
$('td:contains("Setup")').addClass('mark');
```

on page load , that class is added to the td cell with that text , however a script is running on that page , that will change which td contains "Yes" in it, and when that happens , my selector remains with the old td and doesn't move with the newly added one. Anyway to refresh my selector ? New to jQuery so any help appreciated

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your problem? Seems to be that you need `removeClass()`.

Comment: i want to give a bg color to the td that has the text "Setup" in it , however , that text moves from td to td

Comment: And 'how' or 'were' the text moves in code?

Answer (score 1):

the quick, dirty way is just to .removeClass() manually like you did with .addClass().

you can have the very script that changes it removeClass() from every td element.

```
$("td").removeClass("mark");
```

Then again check which td requires it and add it with the very code you have already

```
$('td:contains("Setup")').addClass('mark');
```

Comment: so which function do i run first ?  do i add the class , then remove the class , then add the class again , not understanding what your saying

Comment: okay so you already add the class on load. Great now that's in the past. At some point your code is triggered (that's not on load) and it changes things. That is the code that you want to put this logic in.

Answer (score 1):

**Please read comment below. What event triggers a change to your `td` data?**

```
$('td:contains("Setup")').addClass('mark');
```

You are adding a class to the `active td` which has the content that you're looking for. Have you considered removing that class from all existing TDs?

```
$('td').removeClass(); // This removes all classes. You could define 'mark' inside of the parenthesis if you wanted just that class gone.
```

So the remaining code would be:

```
$('td').removeClass('mark');
$('td:contains("Setup")').addClass('mark');
```

This essentially:

**Removes the class `mark` from all existing `td`s**

**Adds the class `mark` to any item which contains `Setup`**

Comment: When would data change in your `td` elements?

Comment: there is a script that rotates the text from td to td , i have tried to edit it but have failed , so was trying to use jQuery , but that won't work either it appears....

Comment: had a question here about original script but couldnt get a grip on some advice , so i figured jQuery might be simpler for a novice , instead of editing the existing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357911/how-to-add-class-to-parent-tr-if-this-text-is-added

Comment: jQuery has timed event listeners. Why not just write something like the code provided into the `callback` of the javascript thats recurring data?